# Получить XML из колонки в таблице и взять конкретное значение MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Есть таблица, где в одной из колонок хранятся настройки в виде XML. Мне нужно получить значение `<Timeout type="Type3">19.09.2016 0:05:00</Timeout>`, а именно только минуты и секунды.

Вот весь XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ObjectSerialization>
<!--Persistent object serialization-->
<Root>
   <ComponentType type="Type0" />
   <ConsiderDuration type="Type1">False</ConsiderDuration>
   <ConsiderDurationEmptySlot type="Type1">False</ConsiderDurationEmptySlot>
   <Enabled type="Type1">False</Enabled>
   <ExternalRecordType type="Type2">Hard</ExternalRecordType>
   <SiteEnabled type="Type1">False</SiteEnabled>
   <Timeout type="Type3">19.09.2016 0:05:00</Timeout>
   <UsedTypes>
      <Type0 type="Kosta.PersistentObjects.SystemProperty.AppointmentProperty, Kosta.PersistentObjects" />
      <Type2 type="Kosta.PersistentObjects.SystemProperty.ExternalRecordType, Kosta.PersistentObjects" />
      <Type1 type="System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <Type3 type="System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
   </UsedTypes>
</Root>
```

Для начала я пытаюсь получить значение в Timeout следующим образом

```sql
declare @info xml
set @info = Convert(xml,(select [Value] FROM [SystemPropertyStorage] where Name = 48),2)
select b.value('@Timeout', 'DateTime') as FullDate
from @info.nodes('/Root/Timeout') as a(b)
```

Но возвращается `NULL`

Что здесь не так ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Что здесь не так ?

Если сложить селекторы для `nodes` и `value`, то полный селектор будет `/Root/Timeout/@Timeout`, но искомое значение лежит в тексте элемента *Timeout*, а не в атрибуте.

Вообще было бы проще, если бы в XML дата и время лежали в формате `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss` (ISO 8601)

```xml
<Root>
   ...
   <Timeout type="Type3">2016-09-19T00:05:00</Timeout>
   ...
</Root>
```

Тогда получить дату/время было бы очень просто

```sql
DECLARE @dateTime datetime2(0);
SET @dateTime = @info.value('(/Root/Timeout/text())[1]', 'datetime2(0)');
```

В данном же случае придётся сделать промежуточное преобразование в строку, и уже строку конвертировать в дату/время (используя формат 104, см. [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles))

```sql
DECLARE @dateTimeStr nvarchar(50), @dateTime datetime2(0);
SET @dateTimeStr = @info.value('(/Root/Timeout/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(50)');
SET @dateTime = TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(0), @dateTimeStr, 104);
```

И, затем

```sql
SELECT
    DATEPART(MINUTE, @dateTime) AS [Minutes],
    DATEPART(SECOND, @dateTime) AS [Seconds];
```

Comment: Хороший ответ, +1 с моей стороны!

Comment: Чтобы получить минуты и секунды за одну операцию: `SELECT FORMAT(@dateTime, 'mm:ss');`

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky, да, хороший вариант, если нужна строка.